# How to segue to to a different view controller based on label in a table view cell

Tags: ios, swift

I have one view controller with a search bar and a table. I have three other view controllers that have table views as well. Id like to segue from the first view controller to one of the other three based on the search text. Right now there is no error but it still won't segue to the right controller. Any help would be appreciated.

tableView didSelectRowAt:

```
var searchActive: Bool = false
var search = [Search]()
var segueIdentifiers = ["songs", "artist", "albums"]

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
  
    if (searchBar.text == search[indexPath.row].cleanName) {
        shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier: "songs", sender: self)
    } else if (searchBar.text != search[indexPath.row].cleanName) {
        shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier: "artist", sender: self)
    } else {
        shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier: "album", sender: self)
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Have you checked code flow? Is cleanName property as you expect? Have you set right identifiers in storyboard?

Comment: Replace `shouldPerformSegue` with `performSegue`